# How do I use df.add_suffix to add suffixes to duplicate column names in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, suffix

I have a large dataframe with 400 columns. 200 of the column names are duplicates of the first 200. How can I used df.add_suffix to add a suffix only to the duplicate column names?

Or is there a better way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correct you have each name twice. If so it is possible to ask for duplicated values using `df.columns.duplicated()`. Then you can create a new list only modifying duplicated values and adding your self definied suffix. This is different from the other posted solution which modifies all entries.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2, 3, 4]], columns=list('aabb'))
my_suffix = 'T'

df.columns = [name if duplicated == False else name + my_suffix for duplicated, name in zip(df.columns.duplicated(), df.columns)]
df
>>>
   a  aT  b  bT
0  1   2  3   4
```

My answer has the disadvantage that the dataframe can have duplicated column names if one name is used three or more times.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, starting with:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4).reshape(1,-1),columns=['a','b','a','b'])
```

output

```
  a b a b
0 1 2 3 4
```

Then I use Lambda function

```
df.columns = df.columns+np.vectorize(lambda x:'_' if x else '')(df.columns.duplicated())
```

Output

```
    a   b   a_  b_
0   0   1   2   3
```

If you have more than one duplicate then you can loop until there is none left. This works for duplicated indices too, it also keeps the index name.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd

# setup dummy DataFrame with repeated columns
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2, 3]], columns=list('aaa'))

# create unique identifier for each repeated column
identifier = df.columns.to_series().groupby(level=0).transform('cumcount')

# rename columns with the new identifiers
df.columns = df.columns.astype('string') + identifier.astype('string')

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   a0  a1  a2
0   1   2   3
```

If there is only one duplicate column, you could do:

```
# setup dummy DataFrame with repeated columns
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2, 3, 4]], columns=list('aabb'))

# create unique identifier for each repeated column
identifier = df.columns.duplicated().astype(int)

# rename columns with the new identifiers
df.columns = df.columns.astype('string') + identifier.astype(str)

print(df)
```

**Output** *(for only one duplicate)*

```
   a0  a1  b0  b1
0   1   2   3   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Add numbering suffix starts with '_1' started with the first duplicated column and applicable to columns appearing more than once.

> E.g a column name list: [a, b, c, a, b, a] will return [a, b, c, a_1, b_1, a_2]

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
empty_list= []

for x in range(df.shape[1]):
  counter.update([df.columns[x]])
  if counter[df.columns[x]] == 1:
    empty_list.append(df.columns[x])
  else: 
    tx = counter[df.columns[x]] -1
    empty_list.append(df.columns[x] + '_' + str(tx))


df.columns = empty_list
df.columns
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful:

```
col =  df.columns.values.tolist()
col = [ str(x).replace(x,f'{x}_{cpt}')   for x , cpt in zip(col , range(0,len(col))) ]
df.columns = col
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**